# Actionscript to make movie clip invisible before another is opened

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, visible

I have a basic flash document that is showing football fixtures spread over several weeks. I have buttons for each week e.g. 'Gameweek 1', 'Gameweek 2' etc.

When the button is pressed, a movie clip is displayed below the buttons which shows the fixtures. The fixtures movie clip is always there but the button changes it to visible.

My problem is...if I have gameweek 1 fixtures showing and then i click on the 'Gameweek 2' button, both sets of fixtures are displayed because the gameweek 1 fixtures are still visible.

When I press a button to display new fixtures, I would like the previously visible movie clip to now be invisible so that just the new fixtures are visible.

Here is my actionscript:

```
stop();

btn_game1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openGame1);
function openGame1(evt:MouseEvent) {
if (game1.visible){
    game1.visible = false;

}else {
    game1.visible = true;
}

}

btn_game2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openGame2);
function openGame2(evt:MouseEvent) {

if (game2.visible){
    game2.visible = false;

}else {
    game2.visible = true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to propose a re-factored approach that cuts down on the amount of code and number of event handlers.

You only really need one button handler for all of your buttons. You'll also want to keep track of all of the clips that you're showing/hiding. They can be stored in an array.

You can "connect" a button to a clip by giving them similar names (`btn_game1` and `game1`).

The following code assumes that your buttons are all named `btn_gameN` and your clips are named `gameN` (where N is a number):

```
var clips:Array = [game1, game2, game3, game4];

btn_game1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGameButtonClicked);
btn_game2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGameButtonClicked);
btn_game3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGameButtonClicked);
btn_game4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGameButtonClicked);

function onGameButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // figure out which button was just clicked by looking at its name
    var clipNum:String = e.currentTarget.name.substr("btn_game".length);

    // loop through all of your clips ...       
    for each(var clip:MovieClip in clips)
    {
        if(clip.name.substr("game".length) == clipNum)
        {
            // if the name matches, toggle the visibility 
            clip.visible = !clip.visible;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the name doesn't match, set visibility to false
            clip.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer meets your needs, please remember to mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi, I tried to but it says i need a reputation of at least 15 to mark the answer as useful :(

Answer (score 0):

When you show `game1` you must hide `game2`. Likewise for `game2`.

```
function openGame1(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (game1.visible) {
        game1.visible = false;
    }else {
        game1.visible = true;
        game2.visible = false;
    }  
}
```